# I need help displaying a couple of things

Tags: c#, file, io

I am working on a small code that searches an input text file (of my choice). I am creating a search function. So far I got it to display how many times the search word occurs in the text file and also the line number. I need help on finding the word of the longest length and displaying it. Also I want to find the word that shows up most often in the text file as well as displaying the word.

Any help, advice, or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Here is my code: (I have not written the other part of the code. I need help on it.)

```
string line;
Console.WriteLine("Enter a word to search for: ");
string userText = Console.ReadLine();
int counter = 0;

string file = "NewTextFile.txt";
StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(file);

int found = 0;

while ((line = myFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    counter++;
    if (line.Contains(userText))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found on line number: {0}", counter);
        found++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("A total of {0} occurences found", found);
```

I am trying to use regex right now:

```
        var words = Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(file), @"\w+").Cast<Match>()
        .Select((m, pos) => new { Word = m.Value, Pos = pos })
        .GroupBy(s => s.Word, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        .Select(g => new { Word = g.Key, PosInText = g.Select(z => z.Pos).ToList() })
        .ToList();


        foreach (var item in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-15} POS:{1}", item.Word, string.Join(",", item.PosInText));
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < words.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}:{1} ", i, words[i].PosInText.Count);
        }
```

Comment: While you are iterating over the lines, split them into words, keep track of the one with highest length. At the end of loop, display it. And for most frequent word, you can maintain a `Dictionary<string, int>` for all the words.

Comment: What have you _tried_? You seem to have two new features you want to add; you need to do more than just ask Stack Overflow to write those features for you. Please provide a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, along with a precise description of what the code does and how that's different from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to tokenize your document, so find some way to split it up in tokens. So define what delimiters a word has: space, comma, dot, etc.

Then iterate over all the tokens and store them in a `Dictionary` that maps the word to the number of times it occurs.

Then you can iterate over the map and find the word that occurs most and the one that is longest.